# Querying JSON object using JSON select

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonselect

I am working on this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/9Jcs2/). Why am I not able to query the JSON object by using the jsonSelect plugin?

```
var jsonData = {
    "name": {
        "first": "Lloyd",
            "last": "Hilaiel"
    },
        "favoriteColor": "yellow",
        "languagesSpoken": [{
        "language": "Bulgarian",
            "level": 2
    }, {
        "language": "English",
            "level": 1
    }, {
        "language": "Spanish",
            "level": 7
    }]
};

var selector = '.name > *';

JSONSelect.forEach(selector, jsonData, function (resultObj) {
    $('body').append('<p>' + $.trim(JSON.stringify(resultObj, null, ' ')) + '</p>');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly include the JS file from Github. You need to host it yourself or find a CDN.

Comment: Thanks René I didn't' notice that issue at all!